# Where to keep url which is utlised in Java web services?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat8

I am writing java web services which are utilizing other web services(of some other platform) so i have to call those apis in my java web services and it has got url(static ip). Am thinking to keep common url part containing IP in property file. But is there any way to keep such properties or URL part in tomcat? Which is the better way to store url?

Comment: You could put them into the ServletContext. That way it can be configured using the management tools of your web application container. But these things are usually troublesome. Personally, I'd use Typesafe Config, put all defaults into the classpath (inside the WAR file) and allow to override them via a file in a well-known location on the host filesystem (if it needs to be changed after the WAR has been built).

Answer (score 2):

I have always put constant definitions like this into JNDI variables. For Tomcat this means declaring them in context.xml Usually these constants are different between production, test and development environments, so they should be tied to the server instance, not to your code. Also, configuration information may be sensitive (user names and passwords etc), so it is a security problem if exposed to anyone that can access the codebase.

Unfortunately there is no standard for how the J2EE container sets and maintains JNDI variables. For Tomcat, they are declared in context.xml. For IBM Websphere they are an admin  console setting. For Oracle Weblogic they go in the weblogic.xml file that needs to be compiled into your .war file.

If you are lucky enough to not have to deploy on Weblogic, JNDIs are great. Your .war can be deployed to any environment and will pick up the correct settings for that server instance.

If you do need to deploy to Weblogic, you have the following options:

- Use a properties file in a "well known" location on the file system as suggested by @Thilo
- Have your deployment scripts break open the .war file and replace the xml definition file with one appropriate for the target environment.

Note that resources like database connections are somewhat more standardised. All J2EE containers allow you to set up a datasource either from the admin console, or in Tomcat's case by editing context.xml. Your code only needs to know the JNDI name, not the database connection details.